# Mule log is not working if i use synch and asyn in same log4 file

Tags: mule

I am trying to use Asyn log and Syn log in the same log4j2.xml file and want to set the root level is "INFO" and the specific mule package(org.mule) is "FATAL".but its automatically pick the info level for org.mule package and its not restricting the log level to specific package if i use sync and asynch level at same file. please help us if you have any idea. Thanks in advance.

```
 Mule ESB - 3.6

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="file"
            fileName="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}eztutorial.log"
            filePattern="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}eztutorial-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <!-- CXF is used heavily by Mule for web services -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.cxf" level="WARN" />

        <!-- Apache Commons tend to make a lot of noise which can clutter the log -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apache" level="WARN" />

        <!-- Reduce startup noise -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.beans.factory"
            level="WARN" />


        <logger name="org.mule">
            <level value="FATAL" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="com.mulesoft">
            <level value="FATAL" />
        </logger>
        <category name="org.mule">
            <priority value="FATAL" />
        </category>

        <category name="com.mulesoft">
            <priority value="FATAL" />
        </category>

        <!-- Reduce DM verbosity -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.jetel" level="WARN" />
        <AsyncLogger name="Tracking" level="WARN" />

        <AsyncRoot level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="file" />
        </AsyncRoot>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `<Category ...>` entries from your config. (Log4j2 ignores them.)

For all named `<Logger>` and `<AsyncLogger>` entries, add `additivity="false"`. Without this, the INFO level statements will still appear in your log because the root logger picks them up.

See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity